# vb script connection with db2 10.5

Tags: excel, db2, vba

I need connection on vb script with Db2 v10.5 to extract data from db2. DB2 database is on another machine. Though I am using one connection string in VBA excel which is working fine for me however same is not working in VB script.

Connection string in VBA (Excel)

=============================================================

- Set objmyconn = New ADODB.Connection
         Set objmycmd = New ADODB.Command
         Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

  objmyconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XXXXXXX;User
  ID=XXXXX;password=XXXX;Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Persist Security
  Info=True;Location=;Extended Properties=;"    objmyconn.Open

=========================================================================Earlier I am using Microsoft OLEDB provider for db2 in VB script but now I am using IBM db2 Oledb provider. A DB2 client already installed in my machine

Comment: If this is a question with VBA language why do you tag it with VB.NET? Please use appropriate tags

Comment: It is related with Vb script connection with DB2

Answer (score 0):

In the VBA you have references set to the ActiveX Object Library and you declare your variables as datatype.  VBScript doesn't use data type declarations.  You need to use **CreateObject** to Set your object variables.

```
Set objmyconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objmycmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objMyRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have tried the same but getting the below error:Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'con'

Comment: I have used below connection string                                                     Set objmyconn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objmycmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objMyRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
       xDb_Conn_Str="Data Source=XXXXX;User ID=XXXXXX;password=XXXXXX;Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Persist Security Info=True;Location=;Extended Properties=;"
 
 con.Open xDb_Conn_Str
 con.CommandTimeOut=1000

Comment: Set objmyconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

  objmyconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XXXXXX;User ID=XXXXXXX;password=XXXXXXX;Provider=IBMDADB2.DB2COPY1;Persist Security Info=True;Location=;Extended Properties=;"
   objmyconn.Open

 objmyconn.CommandTimeOut=1000

Response.Buffer=true

Comment: I am using above connection, initially its working fine but now its showing below errror ---ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'

Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

Comment: If you rebooted already you want to try a different connection string at ConnectionStrings.com [IBM DB2 connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2/).  If you can't get that to work you may have to re-register IBMDADB2.